# AAD B2C Facebook for Developers IP-Whitelist

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-ad-b2c

for using facebook as an identity-provider i took

> https://tenant.b2clogin.com

for aadb2c.

I followed the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app) of the official Microsoft Azure Documentation.

With google my apps are working fine.

Settings --> App Domains:

> tenant.b2clogin.com/

Facebook Login --> Oauth Redirect Uris:

> https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

I tried to ping the domain, put the IP in the Whitelist --> No Success...
I tried another ping --> the IP changed.

Has anybody a working use of facebook as a identity-provider for aad b2c with
the use of

> tenant.b2clogin.com

?

Greetings,
Ulrich

Comment: Why did you want to ping the b2c domain? And where did you find the IP for the domain?

Comment: any update for this issue?

Comment: @SunnySun: I tried to use it for the IP-Whitelist (facebook)

Comment: @SunnySun ping -a "url"

Comment: @Tony Ju I hope to get feedback from MS support today.

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: The MS-Support gives the issue to a superordinate team. It will take a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Facebook-surface in section
*App-Settings-->Advanced*
the Setting **"Require-App-Secret" must(!) be disabled** for working with AD B2C.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/

After disabling this setting my POC works fine.

Special Thanks to the Cloud Identity POD Support-Team from Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app) to set facebook as an identity-provider, it just works fine. And the app domain is not needed here.
[image]

Do remember to configure the Valid OAuth Redirect URIS and make sure the status should be live.
[image]

Comment: Hello Tony Ju, so i did, too. The only difference is, that i use "Facebook for developers" with a german account. For the login-tests i used Chrome and IE. Perhaps MS will help me: I opened a ticket and send them the Fiddler-Sessions from the login.